# Is there a third party migration tool for SharePoint that migrates custom web parts?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, third-party-software

Our SharePoint 2013 on-premisis installation is going to be upgraded to SharePoint 2016 in a few months.  My understanding is that with the native upgrade option only the databases will be migrated.  We have a variety of customizations using Content Editor Web Parts and workflows that would be nice to include in the migration if possible.  Is there a third party tool out there that would include these types of features?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
databases will be migrated and upgraded, but inside will be upgraded everything, if you have workflows, pages, etc. Everything will be migrated.

**I recommend to do a test migration, when you test migration process and after this verify that migrated and upgraded content is ok and everything works fine.**

You dont need any 3rd part tool.